# Hide field in one2many_field

Tags: xml, view, odoo

I have `one2many` field with `one2many_list tag`, and I want to hide `qty` field which is not needed if I choose for example `service`.

I have this code in my view:

```
<field name='type'/>

<field name="products" nolabel="1" widget="one2many_list">
    <tree editable="bottom" >
        <field name='description'/>
        <field name='qty'/>
        <field name='total'/>
    </tree>
</field>
```

How can i do that using `type` field?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the `attr` tag.

```
attrs="{'invisible': [('type','=','service')]}"
```

this will hide the field when the chosen type equals `service`

Since the field isn't on the same model you could create a functional field on the model of the one2many field where you check if you need to hide the qty field or not

Comment: I get this error:`Runtime Error: Error: Unknown field type in domain [["type","=", true]]`

Comment: You cannot conditionally hide a field in a tree depending on another field.

Comment: Sorry I thought the field was in the same model. 
edited my answer